# How to set default ApiController in HttpConfiguration.Routes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

the api routing configuration from the template is this:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

I have a public class called

```
    public DataController : ApiController
```

It works ok with url like ~/api/Data, but I would like to reach Data controller with just ~/api
I tried it like this:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Data", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

but I get HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
Any solution to the problem?